# Can I have a single-dimension array of booleans that skip indexes?

Tags: c++, arrays, arduino

I'm pretty new to Arduino programming, but am getting the hang of it. I've got a pretty strong PHP & Javascript background, so that's where I'm coming from.

I've been working on a project with an LCD touchscreen, with grids of buttons that I expect other developers to customize to their needs. There's an array that a developer can freely add items to, and additional pages of buttons are added dynamically. Clicking one simply sends that button's index to a receiver.

Now I want to make some buttons "sticky" so they stick on until turned off. My idea was to set up a simple array of booleans, like so:

```
boolean stickyTriggers[1] = 1;
boolean stickyTriggers[2] = 0;
boolean stickyTriggers[3] = 0;
boolean stickyTriggers[9] = 1;
```

What I'd expect is that buttons 1, 2, 3, and 9 are sticky, and buttons 1 and 9 are "on" by default. I figured when I'm rendering the buttons, I can simply say something like:

```
if (stickyTriggers[i]) {
    // highlight button
}
```

The error I'm getting on compile is:

```
array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

I sort of realize I'm re-declaring the variable 3 times here, but I've tried other ways and got other errors.

What is the correct way to hold a simple array of flags? I want to be able to look up a key and get a true or false (or null), without having to hard-code an array length. I'm sure it's all possible, but is there a simple way?

Thanks

Clarification: The key here is that triggers 4-8 are NOT in the stickyTriggers array at all, since they are NOT sticky. I want to be able to skip indexes, or use arbitrary IDs as keys, as the title suggests. Most of the answers miss this.

Comment: whats the array size?  if you need to hold 32 or so bits, you best off using bit strings in embedded development.

Comment: You cannot have this type of dynamic array in C++. You need to know the size.

Comment: well, the code supports up to 251 triggers. can i make the array that large?

Comment: you can use a vector in C++, check my answer below. For 251 triggers, that's fine.

Comment: that sets up an array where every trigger is true or false. i only want some of the 251 triggers to have associated booleans. the rest should have no true/false attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I should have left out the C++ tag, to only invite Arduino-specific solutions.
But here's what I found, which solves my problem:

Alexander Brevig's HashMap Library:
http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/HashMap

As discussed here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=q7rt05n43aa4enp6hepri50pi1&topic=42114.msg305435#msg305435

```
#include <HashMap.h>

const byte HASH_SIZE = 5; 
HashType<int,boolean> hashRawArray[HASH_SIZE]; 
HashMap<int,boolean> hashMap = HashMap<int,boolean>(hashRawArray, HASH_SIZE); 

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);                                 

    hashMap[0](1,true);
    hashMap[1](2,false);
    hashMap[2](3,false);
    hashMap[3](4,false);
    hashMap[4](9,true);

    Serial.println(hashMap.getValueOf(1));
    Serial.println(hashMap.getValueOf(2));
    Serial.println(hashMap.getValueOf(9));

}
```

I can add a quick wrapper to add items to the hashMap without having to hard-code the index, but this gives me an easy way to set up an associative array of booleans, using arbitrary integers as the keys.

Thanks for trying everyone, sorry none of the answers worked on Arduino.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are re-defining the array several times.

In C++, you may want to use `bitset`, check this link

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset

You can try vector (which can dynamically change its size) too, like this

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    enum trigger_status {ON, OFF, NON_STICKY};

    int main(){
       vector<trigger_status> sticky_triggers(251, trigger_status::OFF); // you can add element to it dynamically, default all to off

       sticky_triggers[0] = trigger_status::ON;
       sticky_triggers[9] = trigger_status::ON;

       sticky_triggers.push_back(trigger_status::ON); // sticky_triggers[251] = true, now u have 252 elements
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't initialize the other indices.

Comment: are you using my code? or the one by duDE? what is exactly the error msg? I would suggest you lookup `bitset`.

Comment: tried both, same error. bitset seems interesting, but looking for some example code, not seeing any yet...

Comment: I know the error. Change 0 to false, and 1 to true will solve your problem.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37903/discussion-between-john-smith-and-kevin-cogill)

Comment: but that sets all triggers to false by default. in other words, it would make all of my triggers sticky. as the title suggests, i need some way to skip indexes. i need some trigger IDs to be non-sticky / neither true nor false.

Comment: that is easy to do. you need to define a enum type has three values. I will change my answer to it.

Comment: how would i use/remove namespace and main() for arduino? i've never seen those used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#define ARRAY_SIZE 10
#define BOOL unsigned int
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

int main()
{
  BOOL stickyTriggers[ARRAY_SIZE] = { FALSE };

  stickyTriggers[1] = TRUE ;
  stickyTriggers[9] = TRUE ;

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: The error I'm getting with that is "expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '=' token" on the third line (stickyTriggers[1] = 1;)

Comment: @Kevin Cogill: Sorry, use BOOL instead of bool :) Or by using bool you need "true"/"false" instead of 1/0

Comment: arduino ide says BOOL does not name a type, nor will it accept true/false instead of 1/0 (expected constructor error).

Comment: #define BOOL unsigned int

Answer (score 1):

I think you need somethig like this

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
   bool b[5] = {true, false, true, false, true};
   cout << "Hello World" << endl; 

   for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
       if (b[i]) {
           cout<< "Index " << i << " is true" <<endl;
       } else {
           cout<< "Index " << i << " is false"<<endl;
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: what i'm looking for is a simple way to say, for example, "trigger #5 is sticky, and on by default. trigger #20 is sticky, and off by default." so i don't want a fixed {item, item, item} style array. i want either a single-dimension array of booleans that skip indexes, OR a two-dimension array of int => bool i suppose...

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use this it does not quite fulfil your desire to have no references to non-sticky triggers but it is fast and only uses 64 bytes of memory to map out 256 triggers.

I already had it in single boolean mode so I adapted it to make two maps and renamed it to suit your question..

Basically it is a bitmap.

Compiles and tests run OK for Arduino Duo.

```
// bitmapped booleans
const int IntBits = 16;
const int NumTriggers = 256;
const int idxSticky = 0;
const int idxDown = 1;
unsigned int TriggerMap[NumTriggers/IntBits][2];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  clearTriggerMap; // set all to not sticky and not down
  // tests
  setStickyTrigger(1, true, true);
  setStickyTrigger(2, true, false);
  setStickyTrigger(3, true, false);
  setStickyTrigger(9, true, true);
  setStickyTrigger(30, true, true);
  setStickyTrigger(128, true, true);
  setStickyTrigger(255, true, true);
}

void loop() {
  // tests
  Test(0);
  Test(1);
  Test(2);
  Test(3);
  Test(9);
  Test(30);
  Test(128);
  Test(255);
  delay(5000);
}
void Test( int ATrigger) {
  // testing
  if (IsStickyTrigger(ATrigger)) {
    Serial.print( "Trigger ");
    Serial.print(ATrigger);
    Serial.print(" is sticky");
    if (IsStickyTriggerDown(ATrigger)) {
      Serial.print(" and it is down");
    }
    }
  Serial.println();
}


void clearTriggerMap() {
  for (int i = 0; i < NumTriggers/IntBits; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
      TriggerMap[i][j] = 0;
    }
  }
}

void setStickyTrigger(int AIndex, boolean ASticky, boolean IsDown) {
  unsigned int o;
  unsigned int b = 1;
  o = AIndex / IntBits;
  b = b << (AIndex % IntBits);
 if (ASticky) {
    TriggerMap[o][idxSticky] = TriggerMap[o][idxSticky] | b;
  } else {
    b = ~b;
    TriggerMap[o][idxSticky] = TriggerMap[o][idxSticky] & b;
  }
  if (IsDown) {
    TriggerMap[o][idxDown] = TriggerMap[o][idxDown] | b;
  } else {
    b = ~b;
    TriggerMap[o][idxDown] = TriggerMap[o][idxDown] & b;
  }

}

boolean IsStickyTrigger(int AIndex) {
  unsigned int b = 1;
  b = b << (AIndex % IntBits);
  return (TriggerMap[AIndex / IntBits][idxSticky] & b) != 0;
}

boolean IsStickyTriggerDown(int AIndex) {
  unsigned int b = 1;
  b = b << (AIndex % IntBits);
  return (TriggerMap[AIndex / IntBits][idxDown] & b) != 0;
}
```